# Find the approximate sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that the series converges and find the approximate sum. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}$$

To prove that converges what I did is to use the Cauchy's convergence test.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{3^{n}\sqrt{n+1}}} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{3\sqrt[2n]{n+1}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n(1+\frac{1}{n})}}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})}}} = \frac{1}{3} \lt 1$$

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})} = 1$

Then, the series converges. Now, I'm not sure how to find the approximate sum of the series since it's not an alternating series. Is there a unique method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to check convergence is the comparison test

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{3}{2}$$

This also provides a way to approximate the sum to as many places as required. Lets say you want to approximate the sum to $\epsilon$ accuracy. Then it is sufficient to find $N$ such that

$$ \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n}\leq \epsilon$$

as

$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}<\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n}\leq \epsilon$$

Of course, this geometric series is easily found to be

$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n}=\frac{\frac{1}{3^N}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{2}{3^{N-1}}$$

Solving, we get

$$N\geq \left\lceil\frac{\ln(6/\epsilon)}{\ln(3)}\right\rceil$$

(as $N$ is an integer). We conclude that if $N$ is given by the equation above, then

$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}\right|=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}<\epsilon$$

To find your approximation, simply calculate

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{(3^n)\sqrt{n+1}}$$

manually.